# Cordova in ios blank white screen

Tags: cordova

I am using cordova in ios. All my html pages are loading fine.But, sometimes I am getting white blank screen instead of the content.How to resolve it?

Comment: please add some code that causes problem

Comment: Are you waiting for `deviceready` before using any Cordova functionality? How are you loading your startup scripts (I've seen conditions where occasionally one script loads before another, causing a failure.) Are you using any type of build process (transpiler, bundler, etc.)?

Comment: I am loading a page. All the functionalities are working fine. If i use the  page frequently its becoming white. If i put alert in device ready its working always. if i remove the alert and run the page the white page is displaying without any content.                                                                $( document ).ready(function() {
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});                                                                                                      function onDeviceReady() { //some html bindings  }